# How do I use create orders/quotes in Cognito Forms without connecting to Stripe/PayPal?

Tags: cognito-forms, paypal, stripe

We would like to use the payments feature but we don't want to actually receive online payments. We just want to give quotes to our clients.

As far as we understand we can do that by creating a Stripe account, then activating the payments feature at Cognito Forms, and then selecting "Require Payment" to "Never". The problem is that we can't create a Stripe account because Stripe does not support our country yet.

Is there any other way to activate the Payments feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the payment features of [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) without connecting to Stripe or PayPal.  This is a great way to generate orders/quotes!

When you add your first payment field, the dialog asking to connect a payment account automatically appears (for connecting to Stripe or PayPal).  Just cancel out of the dialog, and you can use all of the payment features without connecting.  If in the future you need to add payment, you can add a payment account under payment settings.

Comment: Wonderful! Glad we could help!